# Regex: Detect pattern in multiline HTMLElement

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

Basicaly I need to exclude `[my-property]` detection when in the content of a `div` but have when it's an attribute.

I have this regex : `/(?<!\>)(\[\s*@?[-_a-zA-Z0-9.$]*%?\s*])(=)(["'])/`

And theses tests :

Should return a match

```
<div [ ngStyle ]="{'max-width.px': i * 2 + 5}"></div>
<div [ngClass]="[
    'class-one',
    'class-two',
    'class-three'
]"></div>
<div [style.right.%]="val"></div>
<div [@animation.trigger]="val"></div>
<img [attr.aria-label]="val" />
<div [my-property]="val"></div>
<div [my_property]="val"></div>
<div [myProperty$]="val"></div>
```

Below should return no match

```
<div [%invalidProperty]="val"></div>
<div [invalidProperty)="val"></div>
<div>[my-property]="val"</div>
<div>
    [my-property]="val"
</div>
```

Every test is correct but the last one, which also needs to be excluded.

How could I improve my negative lookbehind to exclude the last test ?

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/56TkVf/1)

Comment: Could you explain the logic? What are you trying to match and exclude?

Comment: Add `\s*` to your lookbehind. https://regex101.com/r/56TkVf/2

Comment: @markalex Many regexp engines don't allow variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: BTW, `>` has no special meaning in regexp, you don't need to escape it.

Comment: @Barmar See my edit, I need to detect `[my-property]`  as attribute but not as content in a `div`

Comment: Regular expressions are really bad at distinguishing "inside" and "outside". Use A DOM parser library.

Comment: @Barmar, since linked demo had a TS selected, I assumed it would be ok. But to be safe I've provided alternative without lookbehind.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I'm limited to regex in my situation (I'm limite by the technical context, so I trying to do the best with what I have ! ) .

Comment: This whole thing is A LOT easier if you strive to capture what you're looking for in a capture group instead of the entire match.  So, `<div[^>]+?([my-property]="[^"]*")` puts your result into capture group 1 (\1) without having to use a lookbehind.  Now @Barmar is still right about contextual problems, so you had better hope you have no Javascript in the <div> with greater-than tests, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If negative lookbehind of variable/infinite length is acceptable, you could use

```
(?<!>\s*)(\[\s*@?[-_a-zA-Z0-9.$]*%?\s*])(=)(["'])
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/56TkVf/2).

If not, you'll need to match also everything since previous `<` to check the was no `>` between.

```
(<[^>]*)(\[\s*@?[-_a-zA-Z0-9.$]*%?\s*])(=)(["'])
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/56TkVf/3). I assume it should OK for this situation, as you already match a bunch of staff around.

Also, this solution comes with added bonus of lack of negative lookarounds, that are non supported by relatively [recent versions](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) of Safari.